# MySQL bulk load

Tags: mysql, special-characters, bulk-load, loaddata

I'm trying to load csv files into mysql table.
Delimiter : ,(comma)

As part of the source data few of the field values are enclosed in double quotes and inside the double quotes we have ,
There are few records for which / is part of the field data and we need to escape it.

By default / is getting escaped and when I specified the " as escape character " is getting escaped. As we have multiple special characters inside the same file, we need to escape multiple special characters.

Any suggestion

Eg:

```
 id name location
 1  A   "Location , name here"
 2  B   "Different Location"
 3  C   Another Location
 4  D   Location / with escape character  

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible. Referring to [LOAD DATA reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

> Any of the field- or line-handling options can specify an empty string (''). If not empty, the FIELDS [OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY and FIELDS ESCAPED BY values must be a single character.

Only a single char is supported for ESCAPED BY field. 
My proposal is to use any programming language (e.g. PHP, C# etc.) for opening and processing file line-by-line using regexp